# How do I use text as reference in EXCEL

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How can I use a cell value (text) as reference in another cell value (which is also text)?

In the table below, I want to use Sachin in cell A1 in column B (which should change dynamically)

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Sachin | My Name is Sachin(from A1) |

[image: Tried & for referencing]

Comment: Why not simply putting in cell B1: ="My name is " & A1?

Comment: I attached an image above using &,it didn't work out!

Comment: You need to enter it as a formula, i.e., the equal sign is missing.

Comment: Another question popped up!
How can we use multiple values as reference in the same cell
For eg: I have column A where in A1-Name,A2-Gender,A3-Age,and I wanna display in Column B-My name is 'A1',I'm a 'A2' and my age is 'A3'

Comment: You can simply extend the statement: ="My name is " & A1 & "I am a " & A2 & "My age is " & A3 etc.

Answer (score -1):

In cell `B1`, type the following formula:

```
="My Name is "&A1
```

This will work, if the cell `A1 = Sachin`.